# For what configuration of oscillators on a ring the ring will not move?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring

Once upon a time, on a two-dimensional plane. Imagine we place pairs of oscillators on an incompressible ring. The ring has mass $M$ and radius $R$ (though I don't think this is of any importance), while every member of a pair has mass $m_n$ and related spring constant $k_n$. Every member of a pair is placed diametrically opposite to the other member. The oscillators can oscillate in every direction. Let's also assume that all amplitudes are the same.

What are the configurations of oscillators and swing directions for which the ring doesn't move? For every $n$ (the number of oscillators), this configuration will be different. For example, for $n=1$, just let the two masses oscillate in opposite directions, perpendicular to the ring, and the ring will not move (due to its incompressibility). This is the only mode for one pair. The ring will not move either if we place $n$ of these "modes" arbitrarily on the ring (all masses and spring constants can be different). It's a trivial mode.

If we place two pairs on the ring, the ring will stay put if we place the two pairs of oscillators (with the same mass and the same spring constant, $m_1=m_2$ and $k_1=k_2$) arbitrarily on the ring and make them oscillate 180 degrees out of phase. You can place an arbitrary number of these pairs of pairs arbitrarily on the ring, and the ring will not oscillate (as long as all masses and spring constants are equal). Let's call this configuration trivial too.

Are these trivial configurations of pairs the only possible ones or do others exist? I can't imagine other modes to exist.

Comment: 3, at 120, 240 and 360 degrees. A and B cancel each other's y component and C cancels the combined x component of A and B.

Comment: @Peter Are they oscillating perpendicular to the ring?

Comment: Yes. A and B have $\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ in y direction and add to 1 in x direction, while C is -1 in x direction.

Comment: @Peter Didn't I mention this in the question (n arbitrarily placed pairs, oscillating perpendicular to the ring), or do you include the amplitude of the oscillation (which I didn't, so I have to edit)?

Comment: My example is a triplet, not a pair, but two triplets are 3 pairs. The 3 in a triplet need to be the same in magnitude, mass and period, but the two triplets need not be the same. So you could have A B C D E F spaced at 60 degrees, with A C E the same, paired against D F B which are the same as each other but different from A C E.